# How to catch an exception and fix the code and then run the function again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch, try-except

```
global r
global t

def divide(a,b):
    try:
        c=a/b
        print(c)
        return c
    except:
       b+=1000
       r=b
       raise Exception

def main():
    try:
        r=0
        t=1000
        divide(t,r)
    except:
        print('except block')
        divide(t,r)

main()
```

How do i change the value of the variable r and then call the function again from the except block, after catching it as an exception?

Comment: call the function from its own `except` block? use `except ZeroDivisionError:` BTW.

Comment: Further to @Jean-François Fabre's comment: `globals` should generally be avoided. Also, why not stick all of this into a class?

Comment: @AdamMitchell A class? for dividing 2 numbers?

Comment: @DeepSpace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: @AdamMitchell The fact that OP shouldn't use global variables does not justify using a class here. See John's answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do anything in `divide`. It's not its job to fix bad input parameters, nor catch the resulting exception. The caller can do those things.

```
def divide(a,b):
    c=a/b
    print(c)
    return c
```

Make the correction in `main` instead:

```
def main():
    try:
        r=0
        t=1000
        divide(t,r)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('except block')
        r+=1000
        divide(t,r)
```

Comment: this is just an example where the error is caused by the variable r because its zero, but what if after incrementing r the exception might occur and needs to be incremented again then the divide function must be called

Comment: @ShricharanArumugam Then you need a loop, just like in *any* situation where you want to do the same thing multiple times.